# How can I stop Windows from using the "My Documents" folder every time an Open File Dialog box comes up?

Tags: windows-xp

How can I stop Windows from opening the "My Documents" folder every time an Open File Dialog box comes up? I have some programs that are "hard coded" to open to their own file locations. On my other computers they work fine. But on an XP box any Open File Dialog box ALWAYS opens to my "My Documents" folder, and then I have to browse to the right one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is this article
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-more-ways-to-customize-common-dialog-open-in-windows-xp/
THey don't mention "filebox extender" that i love because of these features that you might find useful:

1. Your favorite folders available in every open dialog
2. Customize the open dialog appareance, and default view
3. If you have a file explorer window open and you click it, filebox extender will take ANY open dialog to that folder, this is a great way to get to your desired folders.